# Не срабатывает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery

Скрипт для разворачивания-сворачивания полного текста блока по клику на ссылку (убирает/добавляет к блоку с текcтом класс short). Меняется только текст ссылки с read more на collapse, а класс short не убирается/не добавляется http://jsfiddle.net/J8jkw/9/ Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/J8jkw/12/).

Вместо

```
 $(this).parent().siblings("aside .news .news_text").removeClass("short");
```

нужно было

```
 $(this).parent().find(".news_text").removeClass("short");
```

Аналогично и во второй части кода (с addClass).

Comment: да, спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Разворачивание скрытого текста в блоке новостей по клике на read more
$("aside .news .news_link").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this)
        .html("&#8226; "+$this.prev().hasClass("short")?"collapse":"read more")
        .prev().toggleClass("short");
});
```